# MongoDB update nested array of documents with another field value of the document

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document structure in mongodb (version 6.*). I want to write a migration code for it. I want to rename:

- assignment.carrier.name to assignment.carrier.companyName.
- eventLog.assignment.carrier.name to eventLog.assignment.carrier.companyName.

At the end I want to unset the assignment.carrier.name and eventLog.assignment.carrier.name

I tried mongodb updateMany with $set, $map using stage pipelines. But I cannot make it work because path (.) operator does not work in inside nested fields. I am also not sure whether I my approach is correct or not. What is the proper way of do it.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "64197588267778b51b8636c9"
    },
    "eventLog": [
      {
        "status": "CREATED",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "64197588267778b51b8636ca"
        },
        "id": "K6DXajyH5Iz1YJcMQWET",
        "timestamp": {
          "$date": "2022-03-21T09:14:48.830Z"
        },
        "eventName": "SHIPMENT_STATUS_CREATED"
      },
      {
        "status": "DISPATCHED",
        "assignment": {
          "carrier": {
            "name": "Götzelmann GmbH",
            "address": {
              "street": "Wilhelmstr. 93a",
              "zipCode": "01493",
              "city": "West Carascheid",
              "country": "GM"
            },
            "contact": {
              "name": "Dr. Kurt Köhler",
              "mobile": "+49-2552-44163376",
              "phone": "(0535) 822761698",
              "email": "Melek_Betz9@hotmail.com"
            }
          },
          "dispatcher": {
            "contact": {
              "name": "Ismael Dobbrunz",
              "mobile": "(0414) 033315280",
              "phone": "(0267) 470589844",
              "email": "Leoni.Lanig@gmail.com"
            }
          },
          "referenceId": "CaRK5SmdAOKlk5fcaWKS",
          "assignedAt": {
            "$date": "2023-03-23T10:18:40.543Z"
          }
        },
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "641c279463f157e12f5c3487"
        },
        "id": "K6TyyMh7r0R7dBHKbQHh",
        "timestamp": {
          "$date": "2022-03-23T10:19:00.749Z"
        },
        "eventName": "SHIPMENT_STATUS_DISPATCHED"
      }
    ],
    "status": "DISPATCHED",
    "distance": 168,
    "id": "SpMK6DXajCPPBY1HoXSn",
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2022-03-21T09:14:48.843Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": "2022-03-23T10:19:00.750Z"
    },
    "assignment": {
      "carrier": {
        "name": "Götzelmann GmbH",
        "address": {
          "street": "Wilhelmstr. 93a",
          "zipCode": "01493",
          "city": "West Carascheid",
          "country": "GM"
        },
        "contact": {
          "name": "Dr. Kurt Köhler",
          "mobile": "+49-2552-44163376",
          "phone": "(0535) 822761698",
          "email": "Melek_Betz9@hotmail.com"
        }
      },
      "dispatcher": {
        "contact": {
          "name": "Ismael Dobbrunz",
          "mobile": "(0414) 033315280",
          "phone": "(0267) 470589844",
          "email": "Leoni.Lanig@gmail.com"
        }
      },
      "referenceId": "CaRK5SmdAOKlk5fcaWKS",
      "assignedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-03-23T10:18:40.543Z"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it, using pipelined form of updates, we are using `$map`, to map the array elements and update the key:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "assignment.carrier.companyName": "$assignment.carrier.name",
      "eventLog": {
        $map: {
          input: "$eventLog",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $ifNull: [
                      "$$item.assignment",
                      true
                    ]
                  },
                  true
                ]
              },
              then: "$$item",
              else: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$item",
                  {
                    assignment: {
                      carrier: {
                        address: "$$item.assignment.carrier.address",
                        contact: "$$item.assignment.carrier.contact",
                        companyName: "$$item.assignment.carrier.name"
                      },
                      dispatcher: "$$item.assignment.dispatcher",
                      referenceId: "$$item.referenceId",
                      assignedAt: "$$item.assignedAt"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "assignment.carrier.name"
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SvISdxoZwCp)